# Sending multiple items through the same queue?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, function, queue

I want to simultaneously send 2 items of data through a queue for an *args input however I can't seem to figure out if it's possible.

```
import numpy as np
import queue

def set_data(*data):
    first, second = data
    print(first, second)

q = queue.Queue()
array1, array2 = np.zeros((10, 3), dtype=float), np.zeros((10, 3), dtype=float)

q.put(array1, array2)
c, v = q.get()

set_data(c, v)
```

Does anyone know a way to make this work?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Queue.put` function signature is:

```
put(item, block=True, timeout=None)
```

Passing two parameters sets `item` to `array1` and `block` to `array2`.  You want to pass them as a single parameter to `item` as either a tuple or list, e.g.:

```
q.put((array1, array2))
```

Comment: Finally a problem with a simple solution. Thank you! This worked.